# How to access key outside of array in when condition of JOI schema validation

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, joi

I have an issue.

```
"Formula": {
    "Type": "Import/Export",
    "Params": {
        "ShippingSourceType": "System/Country/Group",
        ShippingDestinationType:"System/Country/Group"
    }
}
```

I have above object in which I have to put validation on Type. But `Type` is depend on `ShippingSourceType` and `ShippingDestinationType` in params.

If `ShippingSourceType` is System then `Type` Should be `Export`.
If `ShippingDestinationType` is System then Type Should be `Import`.

I have validate the Type as below:

```
Type: joi.alternatives().required()
    .when('Params.ShippingSourceType', { is: 'System', then: joi.string().valid('Export') })
    .when('Params.ShippingDestinationType', { is: 'System', then: joi.string().valid('Import') })
```

But it didn't work. Can you please suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Hi Bhushan, can you tell us what version of `joi` you're using? Also can you provide an failing example, like an object which should have been validated but wasn't or an object which shouldn't have but was?

Comment: @Almouro I have updated my issue. can you please help me with that?

Comment: I don't see any problems with your validation. I even ran a [small file validating some objects](https://gist.github.com/Almouro/b88271f2c8549ba9d834) and it validated as expected.
I used the latest version of Joi, aka `7.0.1`. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Almouro sorry i forgot to add when it didn't work. If Shipping SourceType and ShippingDestinationType both are not system, then it should allow Type to take Import or Export. But in this case it gives not matching any of the allow alternatives which is correct as i haven't mention the condition for it. So what condition should i put to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is [a bug with Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/763)

A commit was pushed to fix it, but will be shipped in version 8.

Meanwhile, you can use it by installing Joi from a specific commit, like so:

```
npm install --save git+https://github.com/hapijs/joi.git#5b60525b861a3ab99123cd8349cbd9f6ed50e262
```

Then, you can use:

```
var joi = require('joi');

var schema = joi.object({
  Formula: joi.object().keys({
    Type: joi.string() // Use joi.string()
      .when('Params.ShippingSourceType', { is: 'System', then: joi.string().valid('Export')})
      .when('Params.ShippingDestinationType', { is: 'System', then: joi.string().valid('Import')}),
    Params: joi.object(), // or additional validation
  }),
});
```

And everything now works as expected:

```
joi.validate({
  Formula: {
    Type: "Export",
    Params: {
      ShippingSourceType: "System",
      ShippingDestinationType:"Country"
    }
  }
}, schema, function (err, value) {
  // If I understood correctly, this should be valid
  console.log(err ? 'object invalid' : 'object valid');
});

joi.validate({
  Formula: {
    Type: "Import",
    Params: {
      ShippingSourceType: "System",
      ShippingDestinationType:"Country"
    }
  }
}, schema, function (err, value) {
  // If I understood correctly, this should be invalid since
  // ShippingSourceType == "System" => Type == "Export"
  console.log(err ? 'object invalid' : 'object valid');
});

joi.validate({
  Formula: {
    Type: "Import",
    Params: {
      ShippingSourceType: "Country",
      ShippingDestinationType:"System"
    }
  }
}, schema, function (err, value) {
  // If I understood correctly, this should be valid
  console.log(err ? 'object invalid' : 'object valid');
});

joi.validate({
  Formula: {
    Type: "Export",
    Params: {
      ShippingSourceType: "Country",
      ShippingDestinationType:"System"
    }
  }
}, schema, function (err, value) {
  // If I understood correctly, this should be invalid since
  // ShippingDestinationType == "System" => Type == "Export"
  console.log(err ? 'object invalid' : 'object valid');
});

joi.validate({
  Formula: {
    Type: "Export",
    Params: {
      ShippingSourceType: "Country",
      ShippingDestinationType:"Country"
    }
  }
}, schema, function (err, value) {
  // Should be valid
  console.log(err ? 'object invalid' : 'object valid');
});
```